# Rename RAW files with Jpeg Filenames

Tags: file, batch-file, rename, overwrite

I've tried already to find an answer to this.  I've been looking for 6 hours straight now.

I am not a programmer!  I am a Photographer.

I have RAW files.  I have processed around 200 and saved as Jpeg with individual file names which are all different.

I want to go back and edit the RAW files, but copy the Jpeg file names to the RAW files to save time (Ironic as it would have taken me 20 mins, but I've been looking all day)

Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Could be possible. Could be impossible. The question doesn't contain any clues to that. Anyway it's not suitable on stackoverflow. Maybe http://superuser.com.

Comment: What did you use to process the RAW files, I am sure the software you are using will save the file with the same file name when you process it.

Comment: i have renamed the files individually.  I want to copy the jpeg filenames to the RAW files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're wanting or not. While I'm neither a programmer or photographer. If you're wanting to just rename a group of files in the same directory to have a different extension, you could do something like:

```
REN C:\Path\To\Files\*.RAW *.jpeg
```

Or if you didn't want to have to type out the full path of the files, open a command prompt at the pictures directory and just type

```
REN *.RAW *jpeg
```

You can easily open a command prompt at the directory by going to the parent directory, hover mouse over the folder you're wanting the prompt opened in, press "Shift" + "Right mouse click" there should be a new shell context entry for open command window here.

Comment: Hi, apologies for not reading this.  I had no notifications.

I want to copy the entire filenames of each file from my edited Jpeg folder to my original RAW folder.

I have hundreds of edited jpeg images with individual filenames, but I want to go back and apply the filenames to the RAW files instead so I can edit them.